# Setting Products URL

Tags: magento-1.9, url, url-rewrite

I have magento store with 5000 products.

my product url is `domain-name.com/xxxxxx.html`

where x is a number,
how to set the URL to be the same as the product title instead of the number?

Answer (score 2):

All Magento products have an attribute called `url_key`. This attribute is used to compose the URL for a product and filled by default with a filtered version of the product's name (see `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Url::formatUrlKey()`).

Most probably this `url_key` attribute has been filled with numbers for all your products.

To reset all URL keys, you could empty the URL key for the products and save them again. Magento will fill it with a default URL key, based on the product's name (see `Mage_Catalog_Model_Attribute_Backend_Urlkey_Abstract::beforeSave()`):

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
$product->setUrlKey('')
   ->save();
```

Answer (score 1):

It's Magento's default behaviour that it generates URL from product name.

You should try Truncate `url_rewrite` table and do reindex catalog url. (**Take a table backup first**)

Answer (score 0):

Log in to your database and do the following

1. Do a backup of your database
2. Then truncate the table core_url_rewrite

   SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;

   TRUNCATE TABLE `core_url_rewrite`;

   SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
3. Reindex catalog URL under "System"-->"Index Management"